# How can I convert dd/MMM/yy hh:mm AM/PM to iCal event format?

Tags: perl, date, icalendar

I have a list of date-times in this format:

`05/Jan/12 8:00 AM`

The day is always two digits, but the hour can be either one or two digits.

I'd like to convert that to iCal format:

`20120105T080000Z`

Is there a module that does this?

Comment: I've been swimming around in the documentation for Data::ICal::DateTime but that presupposes I've got the data as a valid DateTime object.  I guess I'm looking for a conversion to DateTime first so I can then re-convert that to iCal, unless there's a more direct route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/Time-Piece-1.20/Piece.pm) core module would suffice:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
my $str = q(05/Jan/12 8:00 AM);
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($str,"%d/%b/%y %I:%M %p");
print $t->datetime, "\n";
```

This assumes your localtime and would include dashes in the output:

```
2012-01-05T08:00:00
```

Comment: Looks like that %m ought to be a %d.  Regardless, this is fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to do it using a combination of [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) and [DateTime::Format::ICal](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aICal).

Also, your output appears to be in UTC/GMT (indicated by the trailing 'Z'), but your input doesn't specify a timezone. So as part of your solution you will need to specify what time zone the input times should be interpreted in.

See also http://datetime.perl.org/wiki/datetime/page/Modules